# Why does Maven complain about supposedly missing method in netty-tcnative-boringssl-static?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, netty, boringssl

I'm having some issues with one particular dependency in my spring-boot project. I'm using netty-tcnative-boringssl-static and have upgraded my spring-boot version from 2.0.5 to 2.1.3, now I get the following error message that I can't decipher:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:
An attempt was made to call the method io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext.setCipherSuite(JLjava/lang/String;Z)Z but it does not exist. Its class, io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/2.0.12.Final/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.12.Final.jar!/io/netty/internal/tcnative/SSLContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/2.0.12.Final/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.12.Final.jar


Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLContext
```

I don't fully understand this error message, the stated paths are the same, on my classpath I can find the library with the requested method.

I think it might be that for some reason netty-tcnative-boringssl-static is not compatible with spring-boot >2.1.0. The method signature in the error message puzzles me.

What would `setCipherSuite(JLjava/lang/String;Z)Z` look like in java code?
The method I have access to has this signature `public static boolean setCipherSuite(long ctx, String ciphers)`.

I'm not sure if that's an actual mismatch, if not then I'm out of ideas, if yes then I might be able to fix it by fiddling around with different versions.

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the JVM spec: [jvms-4.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2) for the conversion.

[image]

So in your case (JLjava/lang/String;Z)Z will transform to a method with long(`J`), String (`Ljava/lang/String;`), boolean(`Z`) and return type is boolean(`Z`).

checking the master branch of netty-tcnative, i could see 2 methods for `setCipherSuite(..)` with one of the method being deprecated

```
@Deprecated
    public static boolean setCipherSuite(long ctx, String ciphers) throws Exception {
        return setCipherSuite(ctx, ciphers, false);
    }

    public static native boolean setCipherSuite(long ctx, String ciphers, boolean tlsv13) throws Exception;
```